# AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('abc(abc)') throws exception: ADMF0007E: target object is required

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-7, wsadmin

I'm working on deploying application to WebSphere 7 using python script and the script is throwing exception at this line:-

```
AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('abc(abc)')
```

If I run the above command before I run the python script, it works fine. It gives me an error `ADMF0003E: Invalid parameter value`. But the same command fails in the python script with this error:

```
wsadmin>AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('abc(abc)')
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('abc(abc)')"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandValidationException: ADMF0007E: target object is required.
```

I can guess that there something in the python script that is causing this issue, but I don't understand why is the `AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints` command is not able to see the parameter being passed. I'm new to WebSphere, I have only used it in past but never configured it. Any help/insight would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Added stack trace of interactive mode option**

```
wsadmin>print AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('-interactive')
List NamedEndPoints that can be used by a TCPInboundChannel

Lists all NamedEndPoints that can be associated with a TCPInboundChannel

*TCPInboundChannel: abc(abc)
excludeDistinguished (excludeDistinguished): 0
WASX7435W: Value 0 is converted to a boolean value of false.
unusedOnly (unusedOnly): 0
WASX7435W: Value 0 is converted to a boolean value of false.

List NamedEndPoints that can be used by a TCPInboundChannel

F (Finish)
C (Cancel)

Select [F, C]: [F] F
WASX7278I: Generated command line: AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('[-excludeDistinguished false -unusedOnly false]')
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('-interactive')"; exception information:
 com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandValidationException: ADMF0007E: target object is required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to fix the error. I was getting that error because as part of the application deployment script, I was copying few of my application jars to WebSphere's `java/jre/lib/ext` directory so that those are available in classpath. In one of those jar, I had bundled an IBM class (`Base64Coder.class`) which was required by a class in my jar and it was corrupting the WebSphere AdminTask utility. When I removed that `Base64Coder.class` from my jar, python script worked fine. I believe, the reason it corrupted WebSphere was that there was a duplication of the same class in the JVM as the class comes with IBM WebSphere installation and was present in `AppServer/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_7.0.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_admintask.html) link. It appears that you have not specified the target object that's why that error is coming.

I suggest use the following command as a starter

```
print AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints('-interactive')
```

**Note**: Instead of copying and pasting the command, type it on the command line. sometimes command editor does not take the command after pasting it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response Prerak.
I had followed the IBM knowledge center link that you gave and tried the interactive mode as well. But I got the same error with that option. Added trace of interactive mode in original question.

Comment: And about the target object, I'm passing `'abc(abc)'` to `listTCPEndPoints` which is the target object. If run `print AdminTask.listTCPEndPoints()`, then it should throw the `target object is required` error.
The command with 'abc(abc)' works fine before I run the python script.